# Babel-node unable to parse jsx, Unexpected token <

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsx, babeljs, isomorphic-javascript

I'm attempting to use babel-node to render jsx views on the server. My current setup is choking on '<' when evaluating my require()'d routes

```
SyntaxError: /apps/webapp/src/js/routes.jsx: Unexpected token (18:2)
16 |
17 | export default (
> 18 |   <Route path="/" component={App}>
```

.babelrc

```
{
"presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
"plugins": [
   "add-module-exports"
 ]
}
```

I'm simply trying to require routes from my server.js like so

```
const webAppRoutes = require('../webapp/src/js/routes.jsx');
```

And running the server via 'babel-node server.js'. Am I missing something about how this should work? Thanks in advance for any guidance

***Updated info***

package.json

```
"babel-core": "^6.13.2",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
"babel-register": "^6.11.6",
```

Node Version - v6.2.1

Comment: Where is your `.babelrc` located with respect to the directory where you start `server.js`? Also, do you have a `package.json` with a `babel` object in it?

Comment: @robertklep

.babelrc is at the same level as the server.js . my package.json includes

"babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.11.6",

Comment: You don't have a "babel" key in `package.json`? That's an alternative way (besides `.babelrc`) to configure Babel. See [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#use-via-packagejson).

Comment: Ah okay...didn't realize that. But still, that should just be an alternative right? I'm not sure why exactly mine current set up isn't working.

Comment: I'm not sure which takes precedence (`.babelrc` or the config in `package.json`), but I don't see anything obvious wrong.

Comment: This looks like it is an actual syntax error, not an issue with babel. Can you print out the contents of routes.jsx so we can see that?